# Restricted range of SV_DispatchThreadID in ComputeShader

Tags: hlsl

The situation is the following:

I have a kernel:

```
#pragma kernel diffga
#pragma[numthreads(16, 8, 1)]
void diffga(uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID) {
    /* code here */
}
```

I dispatch this kernel with the following:

```
_shader.Dispatch(kidiffga, 8, 16, 1)
```

If I capture the values of id.x and id.y, id.y ranges from 0:31 as expexted. However id.x only ranges from 0:7. If I change numthreads and dispatch such that the expected range is less than 8 then  it functions fine. However any configuration of numthreads and dispatch which requires a range of greater than 8 is capped.

Any insight as to why this is the case would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The source of the error came from instantiating the ComputeBuffer. I had the stride parameter set incorrectly.